# How do I programmatically restart Explorer using Delphi 2007/ Xe2 on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, windows-shell

I have a replacement shell that needs to restart Explorer.
Currently I am using:

```
CreateProcess(nil, zAppName, { pointer to command line string }
  nil, { pointer to process security attributes }
  nil, { pointer to thread security attributes }
  false, { handle inheritance flag }
  CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or { creation flags }
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, { pointer to new environment block }
  nil, { pointer to current directory name }
  StartupInfo, { pointer to STARTUPINFO }
  ProcessInfo) { pointer to PROCESS_INF }
```

Which works fine in Windows XP/Vista etc but on Windows 7 instead of restarting Explorer it just opens an Explorer window.

[In answer to a related question for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852995/33732), Robolt wrote this:

> I noticed no one addressed the issue of starting explorer.exe as the shell, rather than it just opening an explorer window. Took me a while to figure this out, turns out it was something simple":
>
> ```
> string explorer = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR"), "explorer.exe");
> Process process = new Process();
> process.StartInfo.FileName = explorer;
> process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
> process.Start();
> ```
>
> You have to set the StartInfo.UseshellExecute as true to get it to restart as the shell.

But I cant find out how to do it in Delphi. Has anyone come across a solution to this?

Comment: I thought it is the first explorer instance which started the shell. Maybe in your XP/Vista tests "launch folder windows in a separate process" were not checked, while in '7' it is, so you're not in fact killing all 'explorer.exe's.

Comment: I am using ctrl shift right click on the start button to ensure that there are no explorers running during testing. For the deployment this is not necessary as it is replacing the shell.

Answer (score 2):

As its name suggests, the [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) property makes the program use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx); the alternative, which you're using, is `CreateProcess`.

Comment: This.  Add ShellApi to uses, call ShellExecute. Done