# Can't start explorer process in c#, just the window file explorer

Tags: c#, .net, process

I would like launch the explorer process, with the taskbar, etc. , but when I launch it (in code) I just have the window of file explorer that open, and not the rest. But if I execute "explorer.exe" in the taskManager it works. It's just when I execute this on a Windows 7 64bits machine. On a Windows 7 32bits, it works!
Si how can we do that for a 64bits Windows?

Here is my code:

```
Process Appli = new Process();
Appli.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
Appli.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Appli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
Appli.Start();
```

And when it execute, I just have that my desktop (without icons) with a window file explorer.

My properties plateform for this project is "Any CPU"

Can anyone help me please?

Thank’s a lot!

Comment: Yes you do get this behavior when loading explorer.  Older versions of windows used to get this from task manager as well but not on newer.  I believe it must detect the process launching it when the exe is loading and swaps behavior.

Comment: What is the reason for loading explorer directly?

Comment: Have you tried passing a directory as an argument to explorer.exe?

Comment: Here is a console app that restarts explorer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10438722/956658

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically restart windows explorer process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565405/how-to-programatically-restart-windows-explorer-process)

Comment: @andyp Yes I've try with a directory as an argument but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dreamwalker I will try the code and I say you if it works. 
Thank's for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you specify AnyCPU, Visual Studio may specify the "prefer 32 bit" option by default. If that is the case, then explorer.exe that it spawns will be a 32 bit process and wont be the shell.

If you turn off the "prefer 32 bit" flag under project properties/Build, then your application will run as a 64 bit app, and will spawn the 64 bit explorer.exe as the shell.

Comment: Excellent...glad to be of help!