# Simple explorer.exe restart script in C#

Tags: c#, process, restart, explorer

I was just looking for a simple script in which checks if explorer.exe is running. If it is, then kill it and restart it. However, if it is not running, then start it.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;


public partial class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process[] prcChecker = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");



        if (prcChecker.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Process p in prcChecker)
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
        }

        else if (prcChecker.Length == 0)
            Process.Start("explorer.exe");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code to explain what and how you have tried.

Comment: I added my code above. It restarts the process if it is already running, but when explorer.exe is not running, it just opens a file explorer or not do anything at all

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788377/cant-start-explorer-process-in-c-just-the-window-file-explorer), it could be your case.

Comment: Awesome! It worked!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t tested it but maybe it´s something like this you´re looking for

```
//to kill a process
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever"))
{
 process.Kill();
}
//to start
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "");
```