# How to start explorer.exe in VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net

So, I am currently working on a time-limit sort of application. Using our home computer, I want to be able to limit use equally between my brothers. Everything is almost set, except the fact that the whole application can be bypassed by just pressing the home button and clicking on apps from the start menu. So, I was thinking of killing "explorer.exe" the moment the application starts after the account is logged in using this command:

```
Dim command = "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe"
Shell(command)
```

And it works. However, my problem is that after a correct code is inputted to be able to use the PC, I can't seem to restart explorer.exe properly. It just opens the Windows File Explorer window with the absence of the task bar and other explorer.exe features with a sub function:

```
Sub RestartExplorer()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe")
End Sub
```

Comment: after you restart the process but the taskbar isn't showing, try pressing ctrl + Esc. Does the taskbar appear then?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using windows 10, but this might not be the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically restart windows explorer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565405/how-to-programmatically-restart-windows-explorer-process)

Comment: Your code works and i tried it, for me on Win 10 it worked just fine i was able to kill explorer and then restart it and the taskbar appeared, there's something wrong with your pc maybe.. Do you have Win 10 too?

Comment: `after a correct code is inputted to be able to use the PC` maybe the problem goes in that part? what kind of correct code are you "inputting" there?

Comment: the code i am talking about is a passcode :3 actually i found an alternative to this issue of mine. It works like butter :) Anyways thank you for the help. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
Sub RestartExplorer()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe")
    System.Diagnositics.Process.Start("winlogon.exe")
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub RestartExplorer()
    System.Diagnositics.Process.Start("winlogon.exe")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Sub RestartExplorer()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("userinit.exe")
End Sub
```

Starting userinit.exe will properly start explorer.exe, with the taskbar and the desktop.

This will also play the Windows logon sound, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Shell("cmd /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer.exe")`